# How would I make a pig script that only returns fields with entries over a certain length?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The data I have is already fielded, I just want a document that contains two of the fields and even then it only contains an entry if the title field is over a certain length.  This is what I have so far.

```
records = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (url:chararray, title:chararray, meta:chararray, copyright:chararray, aboutUSLink:chararray, aboutTitle:chararray, aboutMeta:chararray, contactUSLink:chararray, contactTitle:chararray, contactMeta:chararray, phones:chararray);
E = FOREACH records IF SIZE(title)>10 GENERATE url,title;
STORE E INTO '$OUTPUT/phoneNumbersAndTitles';
```

Why does the code exit at IF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`FILTER`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#filter), which selects tuples from a relation based on some condition:

```
filtered = FILTER records BY SIZE(title) > 10;
E = FOREACH filtered GENERATE url,title;
```

Comment: You can compact `filtered` and `E` together into `E = FOREACH (FILTER records BY SIZE(title) > 10) GENERATE url, title;`. Which may be easier to read.

Comment: Yes, that's a good tip. I tend not to compact since I sometimes find useful to re-use filtered relations later in my Pig scripts.